# Notepad++ assign shortcut key "alt+æ" to a commando

Tags: c++, notepad++

I have downloaded the open-source notepad++ editor to my laptop and I'm currently trying to map the letter "alt+æ" which is the ";" key on US keyboards, to my right arrow key. 
I have managed to do this so far:

In `shortcut.cpp` added this on line 102

```
 {TEXT("AE"), VK_AE},
```

In `keys.h` I have assigned the key with the hexidecimal on line 117

```
#define VK_AE             0xc6
```

When I compile the code and run it, I am able to see the changes in shortcut manager and I can change the shortcut to `VK_AE` but it makes no difference in the editor and the key "æ" still does nothing.

I have been looking into `WinUser.h` as well but I'm unsure if any changes to this file should make any difference. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to [remap your keys using AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm) freeware. (Do not forget to run it with administrator privileges.)

If you want the mapping to be effective only in Notepad++, use [`#IfWinActive`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive.